# How do I make an exceptional cup of coffee with an aeropress?

Tags: flavor, aeropress

The AeroPress seems like a great portable coffee maker. How can I get the best cup of coffee out of it?

- How much coffee should I use, and how fine should I grind it?
- How much water should I add, and what should its temperature be?
- How long do I let it brew before "plunging" the coffee?

Comment: You may need to define "best cup"; do you mean strength, flavour or something else? As it stands, your question is a bit broad and probably quite 'primarily opinion-based'.

Answer (score 5):

The winner of the 2014 [World Aeropress Championship](http://worldaeropresschampionship.com/recipes/) - Shuichi Sasaki - used the following recipe:

> *16.5g coffee, 78℃, 250cc soft mineral water, [EK43](http://mattperger.com/The-EK43-Part-One) grind at 9.5*
>
> Rinse normal paper filter, in standard position.
> 40g of blooming water for 25 seconds, stir 5 times.
> Add 210g of water, stir once.
> Press very slowly for 75 seconds.
> Leave 45g.

Of course it's all a matter of taste, but the top 3 recipes for the past few years are all on that page, so there's plenty to experiment with!